# Matlab understand growing vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to grow a column vector (don't know how long it will be in the end).
I have a test code for it. I am, however, confused by its behavior.
When initializing `vel=[0]` the vector grows fine. When initializing with `vel=[1]` it does not. I get the following error message: "`Attempted to access vel(2); index out of bounds because numel(vel)=1.`"

Why is that? It should not make a difference what the first element of my vector is, or does it?
Thanks for breaking this to me.

Find the code below:

```
   vel=[0]
   k=1
   v=0 
 for i=1:10; 


        if v>= vel(k)
        vel(k+1)=v  %stores all v values, for plotting and analysis of v0 behaviour
        end
        %assignin('base','vel',vel)
        k=k+1
        v=v+1
 end
```

Comment: Why do you not use a [cell](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) array instead and convert it to an array after?

Comment: @kkuilla how would that change anything?

Comment: You wouldn't have the unpredicted behaviour of a growing array. You know the size of the cell after the loop and could the pre-allocate that.

Comment: Cell arrays are still arrays, they are just arrays of references to another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does make a difference. This is because of your if sentence: If `vel(1) = [1]`, the loop only runs twice: `vel(2)` is never generated if `0 >= 1` is not true. This is why you get an "out of bounds"-error.

Further I would suggest to make use of the *i* in the for loop.

Comment: ah, gosh, stupid mistake...
Thanks a lot for pointing this out to me =)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line: `if v>= vel(k)`.

This means that, in the case where `vel=[0]`, on the first iteration `v` is `0`, which is the same as `vel(1)`, so the `vel(k+1)=v` line is executed.  Then, on the second loop, `vel(k)` is `vel(2)`, which you had added previously.

However, in the case where `vel=[1]`, on the first iteration `v` is still `0`, which is less than `vel(1)`, so the `vel(k+1)=v` line isn't executed.  This means, on the second loop, it tries to do `if v>= vel(2)`, but since you didn't append to the array during the second loop that index doesn't exist.

You should probably do this:

```
for i=1:10; 
    if v>= vel(k)
        vel(k+1)=v;
        %assignin('base','vel',vel)
        k=k+1;
        v=v+1:
    end
 end
```

That way you only move on to the next value when an append is actually found (whether you want `v` in `if` test or not depends on exactly what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an index that is out of bounds, but you are allowed to create it and grow the array.

```
value = 1;
value = arr(end+1); %Not allowed
arr(end+1) = value; %Allowed
```

When you have the starting condition `vel = [1]` the condition `v>= vel(k)` is false for the first loop and you don't enter the if statement where you grow the array. For the next loop you try to access `vel(2)` which doesn't exist.